# How to add data in right collection in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to add data in right collection considering by name. The code below is defining well. `collection(db,name)` returns the name of collection. But when I want to save the collection name via `rightCollection = collections(db, name)` and inserting it as `db.rightCollection.insert({"1" : "Righ collection"})`. Pymongo is creating the collection under name `rightCollection` not `Peter`. I want to insert data in `Peter`.  Why is it so? Can I resolve it?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


def collections(db,name):
    if(name is 'Peter'):
        return db.Peter

client = MongoClient()
db = client.myDB
name="Peter"
rightCollection = collections(db, name)
db.rightCollection.insert({"1" : "Righ collection"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pymongo 3.2.2, you don't need the `collections` function, you can just use the collection name directly:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.myDB
db.Peter.insert_one({'1': 'Right collection'})
```

That should insert the document `{'1': 'Right collection}` into collection `Peter` under database `myDB`. To verify that the data is inserted correctly, you can use the `mongo` shell:

```
> use myDB
> db.Peter.find()
{ "_id": ObjectId("57df7a4f98e914c98d540992"), "1": "Right collection" }
```

Or, if you need the name `Peter` to be defined in a variable, you can do:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.myDB
coll_name = 'Peter'
db[coll_name].insert_one({'1': 'Right collection'})
```

Comment: Adis..... By using this `db.Peter.find()` I have to add a lot of code. I need a generic way.. As I described in my question.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that as soon as I hit Post. Check out the new example I wrote, let me know if it works.